# RAC and cell reuse: putting deliverOn: in the right place?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I was playing with RAC and, in particular, Colin Eberhardt's Twitter search [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62796/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt2), and came across a crash that I could not explain to myself.

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/garkhipov/RACImageLoadingSample) I have created to illustrate the issue and base the question on.

The app uses a `UITableView` with reusable cells; each cell has a `UIImageView` on it whose image is downloaded by some URL.
There is also defined a signal for downloading an image on a background queue:

```objective-c
- (RACSignal *)signalForLoadingImage:(NSString *)imageURLString
{
    RACScheduler *scheduler = [RACScheduler
                               schedulerWithPriority:RACSchedulerPriorityBackground];

    return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [subscriber sendNext:image];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
        return nil;
    }] subscribeOn:scheduler];
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I bind the loading signal to the image view's `image` property with `RAC` macro:

```objective-c
RAC(cell.kittenImageView, image) =
[[[self signalForLoadingImage:self.imageURLs[indexPath.row]]
  takeUntil:cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal]      // Crashes on multiple binding assertion!
 deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];  // Swap these two lines to 'fix'
```

Now, when I run the app and start scrolling the table view up and down, the app crashes with the assertion message:

```objective-c
Signal <RACDynamicSignal: 0x7f9110485470> name:  is already bound to key path "image" on object <UIImageView: <...>>, adding signal <RACDynamicSignal: 0x7f9110454510> name:  is undefined behavior
```

However, **if I wrap the image loading signal into `deliverOn:` first, and then into `takeUntil:`**, the cell reuse will work just fine:

```objective-c
RAC(cell.kittenImageView, image) =
[[[self signalForLoadingImage:self.imageURLs[indexPath.row]]
  deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
 takeUntil:cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal];  // No issue
```

So my questions are:

1. How to explain why the latter works and the former doesn't? There's obviously some race condition causing a new signal bind to the `image` property before the existing one completes, but I'm totally not sure how exactly it occurs.
2. What should I remember about to avoid such kind of subtleties in my RAC-powered code? Am I missing some basic principle in the code above, or is there any rule of thumb to apply (assuming there's no bug in RAC itself, of course)?

Thanks for reading up to here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't confirmed this, but here's a possible explanation:

1. Cell X gets called into use, starts downloading an image.
2. Cell X scrolls offscreen before the image download has completed.
3. Cell X gets reused, `prepareForReuse` is called.
4. Cell X's `rac_prepareForReuseSignal` sends a value.
5. *Because of `deliverTo:`, the value is dispatched to the main queue, introducing a runloop delay. Of note, this prevents synchronous/immediate unbinding of the image property.*
6. Cell X is back being used `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
7. *New image binding is invoked and causes warning*
8. `… next runloop …`
9. *Original binding is finally now destructed, but it's a bit too late.*

So basically the signal should be unbound between 4 and 6, but the `-deliverTo:` reorders the unbinding to come later.

Comment: Thanks Dave! This totally makes sense in terms of what went wrong. As for the rule of thumb, mine is now _"get your signals on the same queue before mixing them"_ but I have doubts on how accurate/generic it is — what do you think?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a hard and fast rule, but it could make the code more obvious, more reasonable.